# How do I turn off these implementing types icons in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Visual Studio showing blues square icons indicating implemented interfaces]

I don't know how I turned these on and I can't find a way to turn them off.

Comment: Is there any update in this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Inheritance Margin > Show inheritance margin